# Most pythonic way to get a range from the length of a list?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to get some slices from some tuples, that look like this:

```
classes = ('1 hrs                   A', '2 hrs                   A', '3 hrs                   A', '3 hrs                   B', '3 hrs                   C', '3 hrs                   C', '3 hrs                   C')
```

What I have done is:

```
for i in range(len(classes)):
    print(classes[i][0])
```

Which produces the desired effect of only printing out the integer portion, but it's kind of ugly with the whole range(len(classes)) portion, I was wondering if there was a different way to acheive the same results?

Comment: Why not just `for i in classes: print(i[0])`?

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
for i in classes:
    print(i[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is probably to iterate over `classes` itself, and - since you're only interested in the first element - unpack them:

```
for item, *_ in classes:
    print(item)
```

Note, however, that this only works when the number is a single character. If it has multiple characters, you should split the string:

```
for item in classes:
    print(item.split()[0])
```